# Having some problems removing details & validation of RSS feed.

Tags: php, rss, atom-feed

Sorry in advance, I'm rather new at this.

Below is the full code for the rss.php feed (It's from FMyScript if anyone is wondering). I want to remove the junk that it prints out at the bottom. My ultimate goal is to automate posting RSS content to Twitter (newest first) via TwitterFeed or the like.

http://pastebin.com/vLvUizgx

Example -

By: Sammi
on 22-08-2011
Category: Health

Now the obvious step for me is to just remove say things of this nature -

```
print "  ".$getusername."\n";
```

But when I follow my 'obvious' steps I end up breaking the feed. Can anyone provide further guidance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just some syntax issues. Assuming I know what you are wanting to do, something like this should work:

http://pastebin.com/HfDaQiN0

The important lines being

```
print "  <description>\n"; 
print "    <![CDATA["; 
print $description; 
print "    ]]>\n"; 
print "  </description>\n";
```